# How to pass variables data to Spring Custom Validator?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest, spring-validator

I have a model class as below with a custom Spring validator @UserAttributesValidator

```
public class UserData {
    private String version;

    @UserAttributesValidator
    private HashMap<String,Object> userAttributes;

}
```

I could successfully validate the userAttributes in the Validation class. Now, I need to extend the validation logic using variable

```
private String version
```

How can I access the variable version in the Validator class or Validation logic?

My Validator class is as below

```
@Target({FIELD})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = UserDataValidation.class)
@Documented
public @interface UserAttributesValidator {
    String message() default "Invalid User Data";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

}
```

And this is my UserDataValidation class

```
public class UserDataValidation implements ConstraintValidator<UserAttributesValidator,HashMap> {


    @Override
    public boolean isValid(HashMap inputMap, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {

   //HOW DO I ACCESS THE VARIABLE version HERE?

}
```